# Index Small and If in Excel for multiple criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing

Hi All I have been trying to use the formula below and to alter it for multiple conditions

```
{=INDEX($C$1:$C$51,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$51="Adeline",ROW($A$1:$A$51),""),3),1)}
```

I have a table on `sheet1` called **Data** and a page for calculations. There is a matching **ID** on both sheets though in the table on `sheet1` an **ID** could be on multiple rows. Also the CODE column could contain in this case TEST2 multiple times for same ID but with different Values.  I am trying to in this case find the 3rd value for this combination.

So I trying to find out a value based on **ID** and a column called Code but I would like the 3rd value

So I've tried altering the IF part of the statement

```
{=INDEX(Data[Value],SMALL(IF((Data[ID] =[@ID])*(Data[CODE] = "Test2") ,ROW($A$1:$A$51),""),3),1)}
```

and

```
{=INDEX(Data[Value],SMALL(IF((AND(Data[ID]=[@ID], Data[CODE] = "Test2") ,ROW($A$1:$A$51),""),3),1)}
```

Both Come up with errors - any advice or am I looking at this completely in the  wrong way.

**Sample Data**

[image: Sample data]

**Calcs sheet**

[image: Calcs sheet]

Comment: Put your sample data of table and criteria value. I think you are using `IF()` function wrongly for multiple condition.

Comment: `IF()` function should be like `IF(Data[ID]=[@ID], IF(Data[CODE] = "Test2","TRUE PART","FALSE PART","FALSE PART"))`

Comment: How do I upload the file?.... I have a sample but cant find an upload resource / file option in add comments.

Comment: @harun24hr I have added an image of the sample data and calcs sheet.  I tried the modified if statement and it gave me the same value for all ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** *Change from Largest being the highest rank to Smallest being the highest rank*

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(1/((Data[[ID]:[ID]]=Results[@[ID]:[ID]])*(Data[[Code]:[Code]]="Test 2")))*Data[[Value]:[Value]],COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

Notes:

- We use multiplication of Booleans instead of an `IF` function
- the `1/(1/(...))` formula part is a method of turning `FALSE` results from the Boolean multiplaction from `0` into a `#DIV/0!` error.
- The `AGGREGATE` function provides a method of excluding the error results from the calculation.
- Structured references have been changed to absolute references to allow dragging without changing the column names
- The `COLUMNS(...` function will adjust to return `{1,2,3]` as you fill right to return the smallest; 2nd smallest, etc value
- Note that with an absolute reference, the table name must be used even if the line is in the same table.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I will have a read through and a test later thought what your screen shot shows is the expected result.  So many thanks